# Upgrade SDL web 8 from Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: sdl-tridion

Can you explain the changes that needs to done on content delivery end while upgrading CM to SDL web 8 from SDL Tridion 2013 SP1?

Comment: What have you researched and read? What have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

All the step are well defined in the SDL Web 8 document under [Upgrading SDL Web](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12) section. This section describes how you can upgrade from an earlier version to SDL Web 8.